# Why is 比率 in 一家名为 RATIO 比率的店面备受关注?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Chairman’s Bao has an article containing this sentence:

> 在上海淮海路K11购物艺术中心 ， 一家名为 RATIO 比率的店面备受关注 。

I don’t understand the presence of [比率](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%AF%94%E7%8E%87) here. I know it can mean *rate* and I am fairly certain the meaning of the sentence is

> the business area/premises of a company named xyz have attracted attention.

So, is 比率 part of the company name?

Comment: I think 比率 is just a translation of the name RATIO, although this kind of practice is rather confusing (punctuation marks or other kind of emphasis should have at least been used).

Comment: @droooze I find this a convincing answer and I am a little ashamed to have missed it.

Comment: I really don't think you should blame yourself - as I said, I think it's very bad practice. No other language translates names like that without giving some sort of prior caution, and Japanese for example always uses punctuation marks or katakana for emphasis. For some reason this is rampant in Chinese.

Comment: I always assumed that Chairman’s Bao had English translations but maybe that was just the titles.

Comment: Maybe "RATIO 比率" is the full name of the store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, 比率 is just a translation of "RATIO" written immediately after the name. It does not contribute any other meaning to the sentence.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Hi, I shifted the hyperlink to the question instead. This way, people don't get the impression that the answer contains a link to the company "RATIO 比率".